# Iteration and subplot

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, subplot

I would like to plot 5 subplots with a different value of x each time (1 to 5). Rather than repeating the code 5 times (each time changing x) I thought it would be more elegant to use a for loop to plot each subplot. However, I cannot get the code to work.

On a further note, when I plot the five plots manually, for some reason the axes labels only appear on the Y axis. How can I get them to appear on all axes?

```
% constants
a=30;
b=0.5;

% parameters
x=1:1:5 ;
e1 = 0:10:10000; 
e2 = 0:10:10000; 

[e1,e2]=meshgrid(e1,e2);

% plots

t(x)=(a.^(6.*x)/factorial(6.*x))*...
    (exp(-b*x.*e2));

u(x)=((a.^(a-(6.*x)))/factorial(a-(6.*x)))*...
    exp(-b*(a-(6.*x)).*e1);

p(x)=t(x)./(t(x)+u(x));

%FIGURES:

for i=length(x)

    figure
    subplot(3,2,i);
    mesh(e1,e2,p(i));
    title('X=i');
    axis([1 10000 1 1000 10^-300 1])
    xlabel('e1');
    ylabel('e2');
    zlabel('p');

end
```

Comment: This is somewhat difficult to answer since there is so very much wrong here. I originally assumed this was a Matlab question, but the definition uf t(x), u(x) and p(x) has nothing much to do with Matlab, so I'm not sure anymore. If just the looped plotting is the problem, the first thing you need to do is put the 'figure' outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your code had several bugs. Here is one that works:

```
% constants
a=30;
b=0.5;

% parameters
x=1:1:5 ;
e1 = 0:10:10000; 
e2 = 0:10:10000; 

[e1,e2]=meshgrid(e1,e2);

% plots

t=@(x)(a.^(6.*x)./factorial(6.*x))*...
    (exp(-b*x.*e2));

u=@(x)((a.^(a-(6.*x)))/factorial(a-(6.*x)))*...
    exp(-b*(a-(6.*x)).*e1);

p=@(x)t(x)./(t(x)+u(x));

%FIGURES:
figure
for i=x


    subplot(3,2,i);
    mesh(e1,e2,p(i));
    title(['X=',int2str(i)]);
    axis([1 10000 1 1000 10^-300 1])
    xlabel('e1');
    ylabel('e2');
    zlabel('p');

end
```

The issues were:

1. Anonymous functions are defined by `t=@(x)([function here])` not `t(x)=[function here]`
2. You need to iterate over all the elements of x so the for loop needs to be `for i=x`
3. The `figure` statement needs to be outside of the for loop, otherwise there will be a new figure at every iteration.
4. `title()` does not parse the string for variables.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was aiming for. 
(I am new to Matlab so apologies for the basic errors).